# What is a purpose of PutReplyMessage and PutReportMessage in MQQueue?

Tags: c#, java, .net, ibm-mq

`MQQueue` class in both .NET and Java API for WebSphere MQ contains three similar methods:

- `PutForwardMessage`
- `PutReplyMessage`
- `PutReportMessage`

I understand purpose of the first one because it takes passed message, makes a copy of the message and puts it to the queue but what is a purpose of second and third method?

The documentation for `PutReplyMessage` says:

> Put a reply message onto the queue using message as the original message

The documentation for `PutReportMessage` says:

> Put a report message onto the queue using message as the original message

Nothing more. Really great and helpful doc.

It looks like all three methods do the same. They take original message passed to the method, makes a copy of the message (including body and properties) and sets some control fields like `MessageId` or `CorrelationId` based on original message and put the newly created message into the queue. The only difference between them is setting `MessageType` and probably some conditions how control headers should be copied. But why and when do I need these methods?

I would expect that `PutReplyMessage` will take a new message with reply body and original message with request and configure reply message with necessary fields like message type and correlation Id before putting it to the queue. This version seems pretty use less because I always have to create my own reply message to specify its content and configure everything myself. Once I do that, I can simply use the `Put` method instead of `PutReplyMessage`.

Answer (score 2):

When a message is forwarded, all of the message header fields remain intact.  This includes message type, identity context, etc.  The user or app must have +passall authorization and cannot change the header fields but can only pass them.

When a reply message is sent, the original message context is used to set *some* fields in the message header of the reply but the identity context of the reply message is inherited from the putting application rather than from the original message.  The putter can choose to override some of the fields in the reply message header, for example whether to pass the `MsgID` as the `MsgID` of the reply, put it in the `CorrelID` field or put application-defined values in these fields.

A report message is intended to be used to send application-defined report messages such as `ACK` or `NACK`.  These are different from the WMQ-defined COA or COD report messages.  By convention, the requester can ask for no message data, partial data or all data but the putting application is free to honor as much or as little of the request as it wants.

The WebSphere MQ native formats and message types are defined in the *[Application Programming Guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzal.doc/fg10120_.htm)* and the *[Application Programming Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzak.doc/fr10120_.htm)*.  I believe it is probably not appropriate to duplicate this information in each language manual but I've submitted feedback from the Infocenter .Net manual page suggesting that they could at least link to the appropriate section in the related document.

Comment: I still don't understand the reply part. For me the reply is message answering some request. So I would expect that some headers from request will be copied to reply but the method allows me to pass only single message. I can pass either request but in such case I will just send request back with the same body or I can pass reply but in such case I already have to fill all fields from request manually. I'm definitely missing something. This API is terrible.

Comment: My understanding is that the method is supposed to initialize the context fields but that you have access to set the body. I have made an inquiry of one of the developers for clarification and will post back here. They would also like to speak with you directly to get your feedback so if you have interest, please contact t.rob.wyatt at us.ibm.com and I'll put you in touch. In that event, I'd encourage you to capture as much or as little of those interactions as you wish here for the community's benefit.

Comment: That was my original impression but it doesn't work that way. The call always end with putting message to the queue so you don't have opportunity to modify its content. I will send you an email because this is not my only problem (you can check my last questions - they are all related to MQ and I have more but it looked like there is nobody to answer them).